# How to use Scanner.useDelimiter() to match two characters next to each other followed by a word?

Tags: java, regex, string, java.util.scanner

I am trying to parse a plain .txt file with the general structure

```
[[Title]]
CATEGORIES: text, text, text
some text etc...
[[Next Title]]
CATEGORIES: text, text, text
Next other text etc ...
```

In my code I use this pattern

```
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(fileEntry)
inputScanner.useDelimiter("\\]\\]|\\[\\[");  
while (inputScanner.hasNext()) {
   // Get title of wiki article and contents
   String wikiName = inputScanner.next();
   String wikiContents = inputScanner.next();
}
```

But it is also catching items like

```
"[some text [ some other text ] some more text ]"
"[[Vertebrate trachea|trachea]]s from human stem cells. Several [[artificial urinary bladder]]s"
"[[Image:Bohr-atom-PAR.svg|thumb|right|310px|The Rutherford–Bohr model of the hydrogen atom ([tpl]nowrap|Z [tpl]=[/tpl] 1[/tpl]) or a hydrogen-like ion ([tpl]nowrap|Z > 1[/tpl]), results in a photon of wavelength 656 nm (red light).]]"
"[[File:Gettysburg Campaign.png|thumb|350px|Gettysburg Campaign (through July 3); cavalry movements shown with dashed lines. [tpl]legend|#ff0000|Confederate[/tpl]]]"
"observed is not some nonphysical world of [[consciousness]], mind, or mental life "
```

I want the scanner to delimit whenever it sees

```
'[[' or ']] CATEGORIES'
```

but not sure how I could do that since I'm not that good at patterns or regex.
Can anyone identify a pattern that might work? I've tried looking around at other delimiter questions and the javadocs but it was hard to apply them to my problem.
Thank you for your time and any help you can give!

Comment: How about `"\\]\\]\s*?CATEGORIES|\\[\\["`?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for the idea, sadly it is returning Title = ```Body mass index]]

CATEGORIES: Body shape, Human weight, Human height, Medical signs, Ratios, Belgian inventions

The body mass index (BMI), or Quetelet index,``` Now

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching the title correctly, we can use `positive lookahead` in the regex:
`\[\[(?=.*]]\nCATEGORIES:)|]]\n(?=CATEGORIES:)`

**Explanation:**

- Match `[[` followed by any sequence of characters and `CATEGORIES` string. Using positive lookahead so only `[[` is matched.
- Similarly, match `]]` followed by `CATEGORIES` string.

**Updated Snippet:**

```
String text = "[[title1]] \n" +
        "CATEGORIES: [some text [ some other text ] some more text ]\n" +
        "[[Vertebrate trachea|trachea]]s from human stem cells. Several [[artificial urinary bladder]]s\n" +
        "[[Image:Bohr-atom-PAR.svg|thumb|right|310px|The Rutherford–Bohr model of the hydrogen atom ([tpl]nowrap|Z [tpl]=[/tpl] 1[/tpl]) or a hydrogen-like ion ([tpl]nowrap|Z > 1[/tpl]), results in a photon of wavelength 656 nm (red light).]]\n" +
        "[[File:Gettysburg Campaign.png|thumb|350px|Gettysburg Campaign (through July 3); cavalry movements shown with dashed lines. [tpl]legend|#ff0000|Confederate[/tpl]]]\n" +
        "observed is not some nonphysical world of [[consciousness]], mind, or mental life\n" +
        "[[title2]]\n" +
        "CATEGORIES: [[some more text]]";


Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(text);
inputScanner.useDelimiter("\\[\\[(?=.*]]\\s*CATEGORIES:)|]]\\s*\n(?=\\s*CATEGORIES:)");
while (inputScanner.hasNext()) {
    String wikiName = inputScanner.next();
    String wikiContents = inputScanner.next();
    System.out.printf("Name:%s\nContents:%s\n\n", wikiName, wikiContents);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name:title1
Contents:CATEGORIES: [some text [ some other text ] some more text ]
[[Vertebrate trachea|trachea]]s from human stem cells. Several [[artificial urinary bladder]]s
[[Image:Bohr-atom-PAR.svg|thumb|right|310px|The Rutherford–Bohr model of the hydrogen atom ([tpl]nowrap|Z [tpl]=[/tpl] 1[/tpl]) or a hydrogen-like ion ([tpl]nowrap|Z > 1[/tpl]), results in a photon of wavelength 656 nm (red light).]]
[[File:Gettysburg Campaign.png|thumb|350px|Gettysburg Campaign (through July 3); cavalry movements shown with dashed lines. [tpl]legend|#ff0000|Confederate[/tpl]]]
observed is not some nonphysical world of [[consciousness]], mind, or mental life


Name:title2
Contents:CATEGORIES: [[some more text]]
```

Comment: Thank so you very much, if you don't mind explaining, does the '?=.*' allow the regex to capture the string inside?

Comment: @T.Dakin, just like your regex, I use `[[` as a delimiter. But, I use positive lookahed `?=`, so to match `[[` only if it is immediately followed by `.*]\nCATEGORIES`. You can refer lookahead - https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.